# Dimple.js with Twitter Bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, dimple.js

I am new to dimple and I have been exploring ways and means to develop dashboards with multiple widgets (bar charts, pie charts, scatter plots etc).

My dashboard is divided into rows and columns (as per Twitter Bootstrap grid) and each cell is a Dimple chart.

However when I make the JS call outs, the Grid structure is completely ignored and instead of say 3 charts in one row, I see three rows of a single chart each.

I have struggled a lot. Infact, earlier I was using Chart.js and it did not have this issue. However, it has limited number of chart types.

Please help!

Comment: if you can share jsfiddle or jsbin example, it might be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I used a simple row-column grid structure using Bootstrap framework.